# How to refresh properly an ADF TreeTable

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

I'm working with adf treetables in java, all data is loaded programmatically and one of fields of treetable is an input text component, my problem is when the data is reloaded in the treetable, this field is not refreshed properly because it keeps the previous value (only in the jsf page is not loaded, in backing bean the data is correct), all others fields is reloaded properly, any ideas of what is happen? thanks...

[TreeTable image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nirSb.jpg)

Comment: Are you using PPR? For input fields, you need to bind the field to the backing bean then call resetValue() on the bound field before setting the partial target to refresh it.

Comment: hi, thanks for comment, i'm using autoSubmit as type of partial rendering  in the input text. I added the resetValue from input before call addPartialTarget for input and tree, but still can't reset the value. I have found that the value is not refreshed or is maintained when I expand the node parent, otherwise the value changes. I think is kind of focus or cache that is not cleaned in the tree node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have seen this happening when reloading is done though a button having immediate="true" set.

You can try:
UIComponent comp = actionEvent.getComponent();
2 oracle.adf.view.rich.util.ResetUtils.reset(comp);

Comment: Thanks for your answer!. I added the call of method reset over the input text before the partial target update and that solve the problem.